# W030 Some entities could not be aligned in the text - but why?

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

Please help me to understand the following Spacy example of non aligned entities:

```
"text" : "15) Abstract:“The contribution of surface charge was been quantitative determined” -> Correct the grammar."

"labels" : [[13, 82, "LOCATION"], [4, 12, "LOCATION"], [86, 105, "ACTION"]]}
```

To me it looks al good, the entities are well aligned. Any idea why I am getting the

```
[W030] Some entities could not be aligned in the text
```

If i add a space between the semi-colon and double quote after the abstract `Abstract:“The`and change the entity numbering accordingly in order to have:

```
"text" : "15) Abstract: “The contribution of surface charge was been quantitative determined” -> Correct the grammar."

"labels" : [[14, 82, "LOCATION"], [4, 12, "LOCATION"], [87, 106, "ACTION"]]}
```

Then everything looks ok. I would like to understand why there is such difference.

**EDIT**:

Here is the code I am trying to use in order to get read of this issue, and it works with `infixes.extend((":"))`, however, why it doesn't work with `infixes.extend((":", "“", ",", '“', "/", ";", ".", '”'))`

```
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
nlp.add_pipe("ner")
infixes = list(nlp.Defaults.infixes)
#infixes.extend((":", "“", ",", '“', "/", ";", ".", '”'))
infixes.extend((":"))
infix_regex = spacy.util.compile_infix_regex(infixes)
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = infix_regex.finditer
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically your tokenization is weird. You can check tokenization like this:

```
print(nlp.tokenizer.explain(text))
```

In this case you'll see that `Abstract:“The` is a single token. That's pretty weird and I'm not entirely sure why it's happening, but that is the source of your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @polm23. You're right, Abstract:“The is seen as a single token :(. Any idea how to add the semi-colon to be a token separator / break point?

Comment: Add `:` as an infix in the tokenizer. By default it's probably only a suffix.

Comment: Thank you @aab, adding the semi-colon to the infixes works, thanks a lot :) If I may add, why it did not worked with my initial list of infixes, see the edited question

Comment: It's a regular expression, so `"."` matches any character. You have to escape it.